# FetchXml: filter by today is within the last x days of a date/today is exactly x days from a date

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, fetch, fetchxml

1.

```
 <condition attribute="expirationdate" operator="last-x-days" value="3" />
```

The above will check to see if expirationdate is within the range of today-3 to today.

Is there a way to do the reversed? To see if today is within the range of expirationdate-3 to expirationdate? From the list of operators provided, it doesn't seem possible, but I may have overlooked it.

2. Is there a way to see if today is exactly 3 days before expirationdate?

Comment: Is this for a report or in JavaScript?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as checking if expiratiodate is within the next 3 days?

Comment: @BlueSam It isn't for either of them. If it was for one or the other, or even C#, I could just format it by passing parameters. In my case, I cannot generate it dynamically.

Comment: @Zach At first, it didn't seem like it, but the more I think about it, the more I think it is. I keep having a hard time visualizing it in my head. By any chance, do you know how to check if today is exactly 3 days before expirationdate?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that.  However you could have a flag and check the combination of date and flag.  For example if you had a yes/no field called actiontaken you could do a fetch for records where the expirationdate is within the next three days and actiontaken is no.  Then you could set actiontaken to yes and do whatever action is desired.

Comment: @Zach The reason I refrained from doing that is because I will have many variations of these going on at the same time, so if I used a flag, I would need one for each of those, which can become quite a mess. If there are no alternatives, I guess I have no choice. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe a workflow, you can make the workflow execute 3 days before the expiration day.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another field called *due date reminder* and populate that in a plugin whenever the due date is updated/created and use that date in the fetch.

Comment: That is my alternative plan, which I would like to refrain from doing. I have multiple variations of these and they would require their own field, which will become quite a big mess.

Comment: Sam's answer is in essence the same as mine except his is a bit better because it gives you a history of the date that the notification was sent.  Unfortunately there is no scaleable way to do this in CRM without using a second field to store the status of the notification.  You could use a workflow to launch the action as Sxntk suggests but you will still reach the same issue with how to determine when to run it.